# Count the number of days in several ranges

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have rows representing ranges (`from`->`to`). Here is a subset of the data.

```
df = DataFrame({'from': ['2015-08-24','2015-08-24'], 'to': ['2015-08-26','2015-08-31']})

         from          to
0  2015-08-24  2015-08-26
1  2015-08-24  2015-08-31
```

I want to count the number of business days for each day in the ranges. Here is my code.

```
# Creating a business time index by taking min an max values from the ranges
b_range = pd.bdate_range(start=min(df['from']), end=max(df['to']))
# Init of a new DataFrame with this index and the count at 0
result = DataFrame(0, index=b_range, columns=['count'])
# Iterating over the range to select the index in the result and update the count column
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    result.loc[pd.bdate_range(row['from'],row['to']),'count'] += 1
print(result)

            count
2015-08-24      2
2015-08-25      2
2015-08-26      2
2015-08-27      1
2015-08-28      1
2015-08-31      1
```

It works, but does anyone know a more pythonic way of doing that (i.e. without the `for` loop) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not completely satisfied by these solutions. So I kept searching and I think I found a rather elegant and fast solution.
It's inspired by the section "Pivoting 'long' to 'wide' format" explained in the Wes McKinney book: *Python for Data Analysis*.

I have put a lot of comments in my code but I think it's preferable to print out each step to understand it.

```
df = DataFrame({'from': ['2015-08-24','2015-08-24'], 'to': ['2015-08-26','2015-08-31']})
# Convert boundaries to datetime
df['from'] = pd.to_datetime(df['from'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
df['to'] = pd.to_datetime(df['to'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
# Reseting index to create a row id named index
df = df.reset_index(level=0)
# Pivoting data to obtain 'from' as row index and row id ('index') as column, 
# each cell cointaining the 'to' date
# In consequence each range (from - to pair) is split into as many columns.
pivoted = df.pivot('from', 'index', 'to')
# Reindexing the table with a range of business dates (i.e. working days)
pivoted = pivoted.reindex(index=pd.bdate_range(start=min(df['from']), 
                                               end=max(df['to'])))
# Filling the NA values forward to copy the to date
# now each row of each column contains the corresponding to date
pivoted = pivoted.fillna(method='ffill')
# Computing the basically 'from' - 'to' for each column and each row and converting the result in days 
# to obtain the number of days between the date in the index and the 'to' date
# Note: one day is added to include the right side of the interval
pivoted = pivoted.apply(lambda x: (x + Day() - x.index) / np.timedelta64(1, 'D'), 
                        axis=0)
# Clipping value lower than 0 (not in the range) to 0
# and values upper than 0 to 1 (only one by day and by id)
pivoted = pivoted.clip_lower(0).clip_upper(1)
# Summing along the columns and that's it
pivoted.sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: That's odd, in my small benchmark with a dataset of 7361 rows, I obtain the following results:

- Initial solution 9.31 s
- JohnE solution 3.123 s
- Last solution 0.431 s
- HYRY solution 0.077 s

I'm not confortable with HYRY solution. A great thanks for all your work on this question. It was very interesting for me to study these answers.

Comment: Hmm, those results are surprising to me, but I only timed the sample dataframe provided in the question which may not generalize to a larger (and different) dataframe, so I deleted my prior comment.  Thanks for following up.

Answer (score 2):

Caveat, I sort of hate this answer but on this tiny dataframe it is over 2x faster so I'll throw it out there as a workable, if not elegant, alternative.

```
df2 = df.apply( lambda x: [ pd.bdate_range( x['from'], x['to'] ) ], axis=1 )
arr = np.unique( np.hstack( df2.values ), return_counts=True )
result = pd.DataFrame( arr[1], index=arr[0] )
```

Basically all I'm doing here is to make a column with all the dates in it and then use numpy `unique` (analog of pandas `value_counts`) to add everything up.  I was hoping to come up with something more elegant and readable but this is what I have at the moment.

Comment: Tanks, but it was not able to compute the result with a real case counting 6361 rows. My iPython notebook freezes.

Comment: Sorry, that's my fault and this is not due to date conversion. I was working with a much larger `DataFrame` containing other columns. In this context, it was a bad idea to use the `apply` function. After this correction, it works fine and I obtain the same result in less time. Thanks for the solution and for the reply.

Comment: Sure, no problem.  As I admitted, it's not the prettiest solution but it ought to be reasonably fast and reliable.  Thanks for following up.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a method that use `cumsum()`. It should be faster than for-loop if you have alot of range:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'from': ['2015-08-24','2015-08-24'], 
        'to': ['2015-08-26','2015-08-31']})

df = df.apply(pd.to_datetime)

from_date = min(df['from'])
to_date = max(df['to'])
b_range = pd.bdate_range(start=from_date, end=to_date)
d_range = pd.date_range(start=from_date, end=to_date)

s = pd.Series(0, index=d_range)
from_count = df["from"].value_counts()
to_count = df["to"].value_counts()
s.add(from_count, fill_value=0).sub(to_count.shift(freq="D"), fill_value=0).cumsum().reindex(b_range)
```

Comment: Very fast and clean solution, it works nice, I will use it. Thanks.